# Arithmetics with screen percentage in SCSS

Tags: html, css, sass

I have a `div` that I'd like to have the following width: as long as its width is less than 1200px, width is 80% of screen width. But its max possible width cannot be more than 1200px.

Assuming the `div`'s class is called `wrapper`, what I wish I could do is:

```
$content-width: 80%;
$max-content-width: 1200px;

.wrapper {
    max-width: $max-content-width;
    @include media-query(calc(#{$max-content-width} * (200%-#{$content-width}))) {
        max-width: $content-width;
}}
```

But this media query doesn't work. As I need to change the `max-width` attribute when the screen reaches 120% of `$content-width`, how can I do these arithmetics without hard-coding numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/SimpIicius/pen/NWRvRvN)

In the following I am using `vw` instead of `%`, but it should work with either unit.

---

```
$width: 80vw;

$max: 1200px;


div {
  width: $width;  
}


@media (min-width: calc(#{$max} + (100vw - #{$width}))) {
  div {
    width: $max;
  }
}
```

---

The problem that your question presented was that we didn't have a fixed value when to apply the breakpoint. We can solve that by adding the difference between `100vw` and `$width` (`80vw`) to `$max` (`1200px`) and let the browser do the rest.

```
calc(#{$max} + (100vw - #{$width})) == $max + (100vw - $width) == 1200px + 20vw
```

Comment: doesn't work for me :/ the browser ignore the media part

Comment: Oh, that was my bad. The `@media` was being overwritten by the default style rule. I updated my answer, it now works as expected. @shakedzy